# Java multithreaded environment with timers, single thread executor and blocking. Non desired output

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, timertask, scheduledexecutorservice

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
...
        Runnable blackjackThread = BLACKJACK;
        ScheduledExecutorService blackjackThreadService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        blackjackThreadService.scheduleAtFixedRate(blackjackThread, 10, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
...
}
```

This is the service class run method.

```
private TimerTask initialWaitToJoinGameTask;
private int counter = 0;
private Timer timer;
private Message message = new Message();
protected AtomicBoolean startGame = new AtomicBoolean();
protected AtomicBoolean waitToStartRound = new AtomicBoolean();
protected int duration = 10;

public synchronized void run() {
        doRoundTimer(duration);
        waitToStartRound.set(true);
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffleDeck();

        message.globalMessage("GAMBLE", "A new game of " + AnsiTable.getCode("yellow") + "Blackjack " + AnsiTable.getCode("white") + "is starting!! #ursa BLACKJACK");
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(initialWaitToJoinGameTask, 30, 1000);

        while (!waitToStartRound.get()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            for (User u : inRoom) {
                inRoom.remove(u);
                inGame.add(u);
                inGamePlayers.add(new Player(u));
            }
        }

        do {
            message.gameMessage(inRoom, "This round of " + AnsiTable.getCode("yellow") + "Blackjack " + AnsiTable.getCode("white") + "has begun.");

            for (Player p : inGamePlayers) {
                p.addCardToHand(deck.nextCard());
                message.gameMessage(inGame, p.user.getLoginName() + " recieved " + p.lastCardGiven().getCardValue() + " of " + p.lastCardGiven().getSuit());
            }

            for (Player p : inGamePlayers) {
                p.addCardToHand(deck.nextCard());
                message.gameMessage(inGame, p.user.getLoginName() + " recieved " + p.lastCardGiven().getCardValue() + " of " + p.lastCardGiven().getSuit());
            }

            startGame.set(false);
        } while (startGame.get());

        for (User u : inGame) {
            inGame.remove();
            inRoom.add(u);
        }

        for (Player p : inGamePlayers) {
            inGamePlayers.remove(p);
        }

        message.gameMessage(inRoom, "Another round of " + AnsiTable.getCode("yellow") + "Blackjack " + AnsiTable.getCode("white") + "will begin shortly!");
    }
}
```

And lastly this is the timer task.

```
public synchronized void doRoundTimer(int dur) {
    initialWaitToJoinGameTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            counter++;
            if (counter >= dur) {
                counter = 0;
                timer.cancel();
                waitToStartRound.set(false);
                startGame.set(true);
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer("WaitTimer");
}
```

So what's supposed to happen is the single thread service starts up, kicks off a  guarded block counter that's incremented by the timer task that lasts duration seconds. Afterwards it should deal 2 cards to each player and then exit out of the startGame loop. After this, it should kill the current thread as it's scheduled at a fixed rate, wait 30s and then re initiate another thread.

However what's happening is

```
07:28 PM << Gamble >> A new game of Blackjack is starting!! #ursa BLACKJACK
07:28 PM << Gamble >> This round of Blackjack has begun.
07:28 PM << Gamble >> Another round of Blackjack will begin shortly!
07:29 PM << Gamble >> A new game of Blackjack is starting!! #ursa BLACKJACK
07:29 PM << Gamble >> This round of Blackjack has begun.
07:29 PM << Gamble >> Another round of Blackjack will begin shortly!
```

No card dealing is actually happening and no duration wait time between the start of the thread and the start of the game.

Comment: Hold on. You use both a `ScheduledExecutorService` and `TimerTask`s. Why do you mix both? And you throw `Timer`s into the mix? Uh

Comment: The service starts a thread that starts a timer thread used to create a 30s "join" period for a game. To be clear, the timer task is associated to the timer, which is started by the single repeating thread from the service.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. What do you actually want to achieve? What is the scenario here? Please skip what you think is the solution and explain what you want to achieve (note: edit your question to explain the scenario)

Comment: End goal is a multiplayer blackjack game inside of my multithreaded chat server. Structure would be - Game starts, 30s wait period for people to join, game is played (with wait periods for each person's turn) and then the game restarts after a delay.

Comment: Wait, wait wait. The game "restarts". Blackjack is meant to be played until an end state, right? What if that end state hasn't been reached?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103553/discussion-between-fge-and-isaac-croas).